# Properly alert prop value in parent component?

Tags: vuejs2, dropzone, prop

I am new to Vue and have been very confused on how to approach my design. I want my component `FileCreator` to take optionally take the prop `fileId`. If it's not given a new resource will be created in the backend and the `fileId` will be given back. *So FileCreator acts as both an editor for a new file and a creator for a new file.*

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <FileCreator/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FileCreator from './components/FileCreator.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FileCreator
  }
}
</script>
```

**FileCreator.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <FileUploader :uploadUrl="uploadUrl"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FileUploader from './FileUploader.vue'

export default {
  name: 'FileCreator',
  components: {
    FileUploader
  },
  props: {
    fileId: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      uploadUrl: null
    }
  },
  created(){
    if (!this.fileId) {
      this.fileId = 5  // GETTING WARNING HERE
    }
    this.uploadUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/files/' + this.fileId
  }
}
</script>
```

**FileUploader.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>URL: {{ uploadUrl }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FileUploader',
  props: {
    uploadUrl: {type: String, required: true}
  },
  mounted(){
    alert('Upload URL: ' + this.uploadUrl)
  }
}
</script>
```

All this works fine but I get the warning below

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "fileId"

What is the proper way to do this? I guess in my situation I want the prop to be given at initialization but later be changed if needed.

Comment: The line in the `created` hook references `fileId` but it should probably be `this.fileId`. You also have the `fileId` property defined twice in the same component, once as `data` and once in the `props`. It should only been defined in one place. If you need it passed in from the outside then just use the prop. Could you post the exact warning message that you're seeing because at first glance you don't seem to be changing the props within a hook? It seems you are only modifying properties from `data`, which won't cause a warning.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the actual code. Can you post all the code you're using and exact warning message you get? You're not supposed to modify the prop in the component. Instead, the passed value via prop is saved to internal property of the component (something in the `data() {}`) and on change you `$emit` the new value. If you know how to use `v-model` with components, the approach is the same with other properties.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so short answer is that the easiest is to have the prop and data name different and pass the prop to the data like below.

```
export default {
  name: 'FileCreator',
  components: {
    FileUploader
  },
  props: {
    fileId: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fileId_: this.fileId,  // HERE WE COPY prop -> data
      uploadUrl: null,
    }
  },
  created(){
    if (!this.fileId_){
        this.fileId_ = 45
    }
    this.uploadUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/files/' + this.fileId_
  }
}
```

Unfortunately we can't use underscore as prefix for a variable name so we use it as suffix.